# How to send large amounts of data over local socket in Node?

Tags: json, node.js, sockets

I have a program that uses sockets to send JSON data from a client to a server, and send some response from the server to the client in Node.js. This works pretty well for most cases, but I've been running into issues sending large amounts of data over the socket from the server. In one specific case, when the server attempted to send JSON data, `JSON.stringify` was running out of memory and returning a `RangeError`. I attempted to use `msgpack` to solve this, as well as use streaming, but it seemed to take way too long to be feasible on the client side.

Is there a better approach to send large amounts of data over the network in Node.js than plain sockets?

Comment: Err, don't use `stringify()`? Don't use anything that relies on the entire message being in memory at the same time? Use streaming APIs? And of course your question **isn't** about 'how to send'. It is about how to *receive.*

Comment: @EJP Did you read beyond that I used `JSON.stringify`? I explicitly mention that I use `msgpack` and streaming, and this did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this suggestion will help or is feasible in your case. As  you wrote the JSON sent server --> client for some reason seems to run out of memory and reports a range error. Since you tried streaming and msgpack (I assume in Node.js) and they did not work, *you seem to be faced with a client side error*.

The only solution I can see to this, is to split that JSON into two or three (whatever you find the limit to be in size), send them over the socket, and merge them on the other side. I know that sounds convoluted, and since you do not have specific information on how big the JSON file actually is (before and after msgpack), or in the buffer with streaming, that seems the only viable solution atm.